# Decreasing Absolute Risk Aversion and third derivative

Tags: finance, utility

(i) Show that if the Arrow-Pratt coefficient of absolute risk aversion ${ARA}_U(w)$ is a decreasing function, then $U^{\prime\prime\prime}>0$.

(ii) Find all the utility functions $U$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ for which ${ARA}_U (w)=\frac{2}{w}$

Comment: I don´t think that the utility function has to decrease, but the Arrow Pratt measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (b), note that
$$-\frac{U''(w)}{U^\prime(w)} = -\frac{d \ln U^\prime (w)}{dw}$$
Then let
$${ARA}_U (w)= -\frac{U''(w)}{U(w)} = \frac{1}{2w}$$
Integrating both sides once, we find
$$\frac{d \ln U^\prime (w)}{dw} = -\frac{1}{2w} + c_0$$
where $c_0$ is an arbitrary constant. Exponentiating both sides gives
$$U^\prime(w) = \frac{c_1}{w^2}$$
where $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant. Finally, integrating again yields
$$U(w) = \frac{k_0}{w} + k_1w$$
where both $k_0$ and $k_1$ are arbitrary constants. (You may need to impose obvious restrictions to make sure that $U$ is increasing.)

Answer (score 4):

First of all the utility function, $U(w)$, has to be twice continuously differentiable and monotone increasing. Thus $U'(w)>0$. You have

$ARA(w)=-\frac{U''(w)}{U'(w)}$

To get the derivative you have to apply the quotient rule.

$f(x)=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}\Rightarrow f'(x)=\large{\frac{u'(x)\cdot v(x)-v'(x)\cdot u(x)}{[v'(x)]^2}}$

$ARA'(w)=-\frac{U'''(w)\cdot U'(w)-U''(w)\cdot U''(w)}{[U'(w)]^2}=\frac{U''(w)\cdot U''(w)}{[U'(w)]^2}-\frac{U'''(w)\cdot U'(w)}{[U'(w)]^2}$

$=ARA^2-\frac{U'''(w)\cdot U'(w)}{[U'(w)]^2}<0$

Therefore $\frac{U'''(w)\cdot U'(w)}{[U'(w)]^2}>0\Rightarrow U'''(w)\cdot U'(w)>0$

Since $U'(w)>0$, it follows $U'''(w)>0$

---

**Edit:**
For the second question I have found no solution. Maybe you have a typo somewhere.